# Changing font of legend for gxp OpenGeo?

Tags: legend, boundless-suite, geoportal, gxp

I already changed fonts in all *.css files but a font of content of legend is still default. I think that I made changes in all style files.

How can I change a font of content of legend?

Answer (score 1):

The content is probably generated by GeoServer through GetLegendGraphic? Check out legend_options here: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/2919a75dc3bfb7765091759d8d3a151ae7c46656/src/script/plugins/LayerManager.js#L119 and https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gxp/blob/2919a75dc3bfb7765091759d8d3a151ae7c46656/src/script/plugins/LayerManager.js#L39:L46

Comment: Changing these parameters does not change anything. I have made it earlier. Maybe any other proposal?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/24487202/ How can I use this link?